# How to add some other functions in my tag game in Python turtle without interupting the main functions?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am creating a tagging game with Python turtle. I have created a successful mechanism that stops the game when one of the players are tagged. The turtles on the screen can also be controlled successfully. Now I am adding other functions, one of them being a timer that starts in the start of the game, and stops when one player is tagged. After that, to show the time that the other player had survived. Whatever styles that I have tried, **the code only works when I delete the time function code. If I include the time function code, all of the code will not work, including the tagging mechanisms.** Do I have any ways to include the time function without interfering with the main code? Thanks! :)

````
Player1=turtle.Pen()
Player1.up()
Player1.goto(100,0)
Playground=turtle.Screen()
Playground.title("BLACK NEEDS TO TAG ORANGE ON THE BACKSIDE")
Playground.setup(800,800)
Player1.shape("turtle")
Player1.color("black")
turtle.bgcolor("lawngreen")
Player1.speed(0)
Player1.pensize(10)
Player2=turtle.Pen()
Player2.up()
Player2.goto(-100,0)
Player2.shape("turtle")
Player2.color("orange")
Player2.speed(0)
Player2.pensize(10)
Pen=turtle.Pen()
Pen.up()
Pen.goto(-300,300)
Pen.down()
Pen.hideturtle
Pen2=turtle.Pen()
Pen2.up()
Pen2.goto(-300,100)
Pen2.down()
Pen2.hideturtle



def up1():
    Player1.setheading(90)
    Player1.forward(20)
def down1():
    Player1.setheading(270)
    Player1.forward(20)
def left1():
    Player1.setheading(180)
    Player1.forward(20)
def right1():
    Player1.setheading(0)
    Player1.forward(20)
def up2():
    Player2.setheading(90)
    Player2.forward(20)
def down2():
    Player2.setheading(270)
    Player2.forward(20)
def left2():
    Player2.setheading(180)
    Player2.forward(20)
def right2():
    Player2.setheading(0)
    Player2.forward(20)
def bounce1():
    Player1.right(180)
    Player1.forward(10)
def bounce2():
    Player2.right(180)
    Player2.forward(10)
  
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(up1,"t")
turtle.onkeypress(down1,"g")
turtle.onkeypress(left1,"f")
turtle.onkeypress(right1,"h")
turtle.onkeypress(up2,"Up")
turtle.onkeypress(down2,"Down")
turtle.onkeypress(left2,"Left")
turtle.onkeypress(right2,"Right")

import time
Score=0

for i in range(50):
    time.sleep(1)
    Score=Score+1
        
        
if Player1.xcor<-395 or Player1.xcor>395 or Player1.ycor<-395 or Player1.ycor>395:
    bounce1()
if Player2.xcor<-395 or Player2.xcor>395 or Player2.ycor<-395 or Player2.ycor>395:
    bounce2()
        
if Score==50:
    Pen2.write("Times up!, Orange wins",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
    

while True:
    Player1.forward(0)
    Player2.forward(0)
    if Player1.distance(Player2)<10:
        Pen.write("Black has tagged Orange's backside!!!!!!!",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
        break```
````

Comment: If you need to ask, this is the error statement:
```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6a6796dece88> in <module>
     80 
     81 
---> 82 if Player1.xcor<-395 or Player1.xcor>395 or Player1.ycor<-395 or Player1.ycor>395:
     83     bounce1()
     84 if Player2.xcor<-395 or Player2.xcor>395 or Player2.ycor<-395 or Player2.ycor>395:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your comment was because you missed `()` after `xcor` and `ycor`. So that becomes.

```
if Player1.xcor()<-395 or Player1.xcor()>395 or Player1.ycor()<-395 or Player1.ycor()>395:
    bounce1()
if Player2.xcor()<-395 or Player2.xcor()>395 or Player2.ycor()<-395 or Player2.ycor()>395:
    bounce2()
```

As for having a score that increases every second you need to have a thread that runs in the background.

```
Score = 0

def Start_Timer():
    global Score
    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(1)
        Score=Score+1

Timer = threading.Thread(target=Start_Timer, daemon=True)
Timer.start()
```

Combining all

```
import threading
import turtle

Score = 0

def Start_Timer():
    global Score
    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(1)
        Score=Score+1

Timer = threading.Thread(target=Start_Timer, daemon=True)
Timer.start()

Player1=turtle.Pen()
Player1.up()
Player1.goto(100,0)
Playground=turtle.Screen()
Playground.title("BLACK NEEDS TO TAG ORANGE ON THE BACKSIDE")
Playground.setup(800,800)
Player1.shape("turtle")
Player1.color("black")
turtle.bgcolor("lawngreen")
Player1.speed(0)
Player1.pensize(10)
Player2=turtle.Pen()
Player2.up()
Player2.goto(-100,0)
Player2.shape("turtle")
Player2.color("orange")
Player2.speed(0)
Player2.pensize(10)
Pen=turtle.Pen()
Pen.up()
Pen.goto(-300,300)
Pen.down()
Pen.hideturtle
Pen2=turtle.Pen()
Pen2.up()
Pen2.goto(-300,100)
Pen2.down()
Pen2.hideturtle



def up1():
    Player1.setheading(90)
    Player1.forward(20)
def down1():
    Player1.setheading(270)
    Player1.forward(20)
def left1():
    Player1.setheading(180)
    Player1.forward(20)
def right1():
    Player1.setheading(0)
    Player1.forward(20)
def up2():
    Player2.setheading(90)
    Player2.forward(20)
def down2():
    Player2.setheading(270)
    Player2.forward(20)
def left2():
    Player2.setheading(180)
    Player2.forward(20)
def right2():
    Player2.setheading(0)
    Player2.forward(20)
def bounce1():
    Player1.right(180)
    Player1.forward(10)
def bounce2():
    Player2.right(180)
    Player2.forward(10)
  
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(up1,"t")
turtle.onkeypress(down1,"g")
turtle.onkeypress(left1,"f")
turtle.onkeypress(right1,"h")
turtle.onkeypress(up2,"Up")
turtle.onkeypress(down2,"Down")
turtle.onkeypress(left2,"Left")
turtle.onkeypress(right2,"Right")        
        
if Player1.xcor()<-395 or Player1.xcor()>395 or Player1.ycor()<-395 or Player1.ycor()>395:
    bounce1()
if Player2.xcor()<-395 or Player2.xcor()>395 or Player2.ycor()<-395 or Player2.ycor()>395:
    bounce2()

while True:
    if Score==50:
        Pen2.write("Times up!, Orange wins",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
    Player1.forward(0)
    Player2.forward(0)
    if Player1.distance(Player2)<10:
        Pen.write("Black has tagged Orange's backside!!!!!!! with score {0}".format(Score),font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
        break
```

*You can upvote and accept this answer if it solved the problem.*

Output

[image]